# Random Effects, Linear Mixed Model with Partial Crossed Factors and Unbalanced Data

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I am attempting to construct a Linear Mixed Effects Model with Partially Crossed Factors with repeated measures and replication.

Force was measured at the three locations on the foot (Toe vs Arch vs Heel) as subjects walked through a course in two different types of boots, over two types of terrain. The dataset is unbalanced (incomplete data for a few subjects).

The **DV** is peak force during each step, but this is tied to a factor (possibly a random effect) of **Location** of the measurement(@ the toe, arch, and heel). So for each step, there are three force measurements (**DVs**) corresponding the 3 locations on the foot. So there are repeated measures (on each subject) and replication (of each step).

For random effects I'm including the Subject ID (12 subjects) and each step they took (a total of 1455 steps from the 12 subjects).  For a given step $i$:

$Step_i$, the three force values measured at the $Toe_i$, $Arch_i$, and $Heel_i$, are compared to one another (similar to a pair-wise comparison) but the variance between each step is not of interest.

Level 1 fixed effects  include, gender (M vs F), footwear (Boot 1 vs Boot 2), leg (Dominant vs Non-Dominant), and terrain (smooth vs rocky).

Here is a sample of the data structure, for one combination of boot/terrain measurement on one leg of one subject. **Step_No = 1** for **Toe** also corresponds to **Step_No = 1** for **Arch** and **Step_No = 1** for **Heel**. The force data has been normalized by it's mean, and transformed (Box Cox), though I read somewhere this is not appropriate for LMMs?

`Force      Subject Leg Terrain Gender  Boot    Location    Step_No
0.215644547     S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Toe         1
2.594064965     S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Toe         2
-1.959028364    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Toe         3
-2.488808321    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Toe         4
-4.08184248     S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Toe         5
-3.664827604    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Arch        1
-7.866304099    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Arch        2
0.636285727     S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Arch        3
-2.810573171    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Arch        4
-2.105803967    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Arch        5
-7.894349142    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Heel        1
-17.60002905    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Heel        2
-12.20433197    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Heel        3
-8.534264312    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Heel        4
-13.75456182    S1  Dom Rocky   F     Boot_1    Heel        5`

I have attempted setting up a linear model with the random effects using the following code in R, but the model fails to converge (see screenshot of errors generated below):

`library(lme4)
walk$Step_No <-factor(walk$Step_No)
lme1 <-lmer(Force ~ (1 + Step_No*Location | Subject),data = walk, REML = F)`

Any insight into how best to cross/nest these effects is greatly appreciated.

[image: Warnings/Errors generated with the above model]